# Change behaviour of command depending on the presence of a symbol in the input or on the width of the input

Tags: conditionals

I want to have a `\newcommand{\inspect}[1]{...}` such that either:

1. It behaves differently depending on whether the input contains a certain symbol. For example, something like:

   ```
   \newcommand{\inspect}[1]{
       \ifthenelse{"#1 contains a '<' or a '\in'"}{#1}{aaa}
   }
   ```

   where I expect the test could be done with a regex.

or

2. It behaves differently depending on the width of the input. For example, with the packages `ifthen` and `calc` I would write:

   ```
   \newcommand{\inspect}[1]{
       \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\widthof{#1} < \widthof{aaa}}}{#1}{aaa}
   }
   ```

   except this doesn't work (I think because the `\widthof` command has can't be used in this setting)

---

By the way, the specific reason I want this, is that I created a macro along the lines of:

```
\newcommand{\Forall}[1]{\forall \, #1 \,\,}
```

and use it extensively in two very different contexts: when the quantified expression is simple, and when it is something like `x \in X`. In the second case I need more space between the quantified expression and the rest of the formula than in the first case. And I don't want to do this manually, as it would be *a lot* of work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard method for checking whether an atomic formula contains a relation symbol: typeset it twice, once normally and once with `\thickmuskip=0mu`. If the result in the first case is larger than in the second case, then there is a relation symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\inspect}[1]{%
  \def\inspectspace{\mskip6mu\relax}% the same as \,\,
  \sbox\z@{$#1$}% normal spacing
  \sbox\tw@{\thickmuskip=0mu$#1$}% zero spacing around relations
  \ifdim\wd\tw@<\wd\z@ \def\inspectspace{\mskip12mu\relax}\fi % double
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Forall}[1]{%
  \inspect{#1}%
  \forall\,#1\inspectspace
}

\begin{document}

$\Forall{x}f(x)$

$\Forall{x\in y}f(x)$

$\Forall{x<y}f(x)$

$\Forall{x>y}f(x)$

$\Forall{x\neq y}f(x)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If `ifthenelse` doesn't work with `calc` syntax like `\widthof` complain to the author of that package but I'd just use tex tests directly.

```
\newcommand{\inspect}[1]{%%%%
     \setbox0\hbox{$#1$}%
     \setbox2\hbox{$aaa$}%
    \ifdim\wd0<\wd2 \fooa\else\foob\fi
}

\newcommand\fooa{something with \box0}

\newcommand\fooa{something else with \box0}
```

This is assuming that you don't need this in superscripts etc (in which case need a more complicated construct so the box measurement works at smaller sizes)

Answer (score 1):

Conditioning on whether or not `<textA>` is in `<textB>` is possible via pdfTeX's `\pdfmatch{<textA>}{<textB>}`. The result is `-1` for an invalid `<textA>`, `0` if no match is found, or `1` if `<textA>` is matched within `<textB>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\inspect}[1]{
  #1
  \mbox{ contains }
  \ifnum\pdfmatch{<}{#1}=1
    {<}
  \fi
  \ifnum\pdfmatch{\in}{#1}=1
    {\in}
  \fi
  }

\begin{document}

$\inspect{x}$

$\inspect{x \in X}$

$\inspect{x > X}$

$\inspect{x < X}$

\end{document}
```

See section **8.15 Strings** of the [pdfTeX user manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\inspect[1]{%
  \def\matchresult{F}%
  \haslt#1<\relax%
  \hasin#1\in\relax%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}%
  \ifdim\wd0<3ex\relax\def\matchresult{T}\fi%
  \if T\matchresult #1\else \textbf{*$#1$*}\fi%
}
\def\haslt#1<#2\relax{\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\def\matchresult{T}\fi}
\def\hasin#1\in#2\relax{\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\def\matchresult{T}\fi}
\begin{document}
$\inspect{A}$ is short enough to pass test

$\inspect{A B C}$ fails test

$\inspect{B < C}$ includes less than and passes test

$\inspect{x \in y}$ includes in and passes test
\end{document}
```

[image]